# Error deploying ADF App (Fusion Web Application) to JBOSS 7 AS

Tags: jboss, jar, oracle-adf

When i'm deploying ADF App in JBOSS AppServer it gives me the following error:

```
[02:53:17 PM] Target platform is  (JBoss 5.x).
[02:53:17 PM] Running dependency analysis...
[02:53:17 PM] Building...
[02:53:17 PM] Deploying profile...
[02:53:17 PM] ADF shared library is not available, implicitly deploying library ADF Controller Runtime 
[02:53:17 PM] ADF shared library is not available, implicitly deploying library ADF Controller Schema 
[02:53:17 PM] ADF shared library is not available, implicitly deploying library ADF Page Flow Runtime 
[02:53:18 PM] Wrote Web Application Module to C:\JDeveloper\mywork\ola\ViewController\deploy\ola_ViewController_webapp.war
[02:54:48 PM] Copied C:\JDeveloper\mywork\ola\ViewController\deploy\ola_ViewController_webapp.war to //10.10.1.11/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/ola_ViewController_webapp.war
[02:54:48 PM] Elapsed time for deployment:  1 minute, 30 seconds
[02:54:48 PM] ----  Deployment finished.  ----
```

On the JBoss side it gives me the stack error:
http://justpaste.it/zom

I guess the problem is that is missing the three .jar classes but i can´t find it anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does your deployment EAR file contains the libraries for Oracle ADF Faces where the missing class is - oracle.adf.view.faces.bi.webapp.GraphServlet d

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your web.xml is configured to have the jspx files handled by the Faces servlet.
Looks like right now it just sees this as a text file that needs to be delivered "as is".

Comment: <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
    <param-value>*.jsf;*.xhtml;</param-value>
  </context-param>

Is this the line in web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- The deployment ear file needs the ADF libraries.
- Add /faces/ to your url, for example: `http://localhost:8080/warfilename/faces/page.jsf`